# Returning order of appearances in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a column showing the order of the number of times the number has appeared.

To give you an example

```
cell    order
012       1  
012       2
012       3
013       1
014       1
012       4
014       2
015       1
014       3
015       2
014       4
```

I know I can return the total number of appearances using count or size:

```
df.groupby('cell')['cell'].transform('count')
```

but this returns total number of times each cell number appears

Comment: You're close, use `cumcount` : `df['order'] = df.groupby('cell').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: Alternatively:  `df['order'] = df.assign(v=1).groupby('cell')['v'].transform('cumsum')`